# htaccess file content changes after page visited

Tags: php, .htaccess, mamp

I am working on a WordPress site, but I think the problem is not caused by WordPress.

I'd like to enable url rewrite. For this, I change the content of the `.htaccess` file. After that the url rewrite works and I can visit the custom urls. But when I visit a page, the content of the `.htaccess` changes (reverts to the default). I try making the file read only but it does not help. When I visit a page, it is overwritten.

Any ideas why this happens?

Edit: I am working on a local copy of a site, on a Mac, using MAMP. The live site is working without any problems.